# MVC - One Page different URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I Have one view page, of which the content ain't always the same, ie: partial views are loaded on demand.

What i want to achieve is:

Allow users to create Virtual Pages (each with it's own url), but the pages must all point to that view.

I hope i am making sence.

Any idea's?

I have already looked at: http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close but I would say from a MVC point of view you need a custom routing engine that you can plug lookup custom URL and point them to the single view.

[Scott Gothrie MVC Url Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

Comment: spot on, thanx. Good understanding of routing was required